# Is my API a REST architekture?

Tags: python, json, web-services, rest

I'm currently designing a webservice in Python with Flask. I now got very confused if it is a RESTful service or just a regular webservice. I've been reading quite a few sources about RESTful services, but still I'm not able to say if my service is a REST architekture or not. 
The requests to my API are stateless.

Here is what I have:

```
from flask import Flask,request
if __name__ == "__main__":
    appLogger.info("RestFul service initialized and started")
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=int("80"),debug=True)

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST'])
def add():
    """
    This function is mapped to the POST request of the REST interface
    """
    #check if a JSON object is declared in the header
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' and request.data:
            try:
                data = json.dumps(request.json)
            #check if recieved JSON object is valid according to the scheme
            #if (validateJSON(data)):
                try:
                    saveToMongo(data)
                    appLogger.info("Record saved to MongoDB")
                    return "JSON Message saved in MongoDB"
                except:
                    appLogger.error("Could not write to MongoDB")
            except:
                appLogger.error("Recieved invalid JSON")
    else:
        appLogger.error("Content-Type not defined or empty content")
    raise FailedRequest
```

I non of the possible responses, I'll return a json, which is actually the payload of a request. It's always a regular http-response with a custome text as a result description.
Is that right, that because of this fact, it is not a RESTful service, and if I want to call it a RESTful service, that I would need to return back a json object? Or am I completely wrong? Is my API just a simple RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one resource `/` to which a `POST` request can be made. There is no way to `GET` a collection of objects or a single object saved in this way.

One could argue that suche a trivial system does not violate any REST principle. But I think this is not enough to call a system RESTful. It is a trivial RPC system with a single anonymous 'save' method.

Comment: In future, there will be another GET request, that will have a json object as payload for the request and the response. But I cannot say yet, if the response data will be generated or is taken from a existing collection. Does this matter to a REST architekture? Can response data be generated or is it then an RCP?

Comment: A GET request with a body? Why? What would the URL look like? What would the body mean?

Comment: The response body (return value), which is the interesting part of the request, depends on the request body (parameters). That's why I thought this should be a GET request. I guess I should make it a POST request, because the request already contains a body?
I think this is defenitly a RPC then, right?

Comment: Yes, that is RPC, not REST.

Comment: Thank you, I think this flipped a switch :)